# Which class implements the factory method?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is the factory method in the factory method pattern part of a dedicated factory object or part of the business object where I want to use the method?

Basically, will I need to inject a factory object from where I create objects or does the object become a factory itself and I simply call the implemented method to create an object?

In the first case I don't see the advantage of a factory method over a simple factory object where I can e.g. `animalFactory.createDog()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the factory method in the factory method pattern part of a dedicated factory object or part of the business object where I want to use the method?

Both are acceptable.  If it’s part of the business object class, it needs to be a static method.

> …does the object become a factory itself

No.  Think of real-world factories:  a car is not a factory and does not make more cars.  A can of soup does not make more cans of soup.

For examples of *factory methods,* look at [NumberFormat.getNumberInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getNumberInstance()) and [DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance()).  Factory methods are static methods which may be present on the same class, but because they are static, they are not methods of any actual object.

Sometimes factory logic is complex enough that it requires a separate *factory class.*  Examples of this are the [DocumentBuilderFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) and [DriverManager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DriverManager.html).

In nearly all cases, the objects produced by the factory do not have factory methods for creating the same type of object.<sup>†</sup>

- NumberFormat.getNumberInstance is a static method which creates a NumberFormat, but a NumberFormat object is not capable of producing NumberFormats.
- DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance is a static method which creates a DateFormat, but a DateFormat object is not capable of producing DateFormats.
- A DocumentBuilderFactory is an object which creates DocumentBuilders, but DocumentBuilder objects are not capable of producing more DocumentBuilders.
- DriverManager.getConnection creates Connection objects, but Connection objects are not capable of producing more Connection objects.

> In the first case I don't see the advantage of a factory method over a simple factory object where I can e.g. `animalFactory.createDog()`.

Having factory methods as static methods of the target class is convenient.  They’re easier for new developers to find, since it doesn’t require knowing to look for a separate factory class.  And it makes the overall public API a little more compact.  Other than those things, there isn’t a significant advantage.

<sup>† There are some cases where this isn’t true;  *immutable* objects may have non-static methods which produce different immutable objects, like String.replace, LocalDate.plusDays, and URI.resolve.  These aren’t usually considered factory methods, but they’re similar.</sup>

Comment: [Static factory methods](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-factory/info) are an entirely separate pattern from the [Factory Method Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/factory-method/info) in the GoF Book. Also beware that classes naming themselves XYZFactory or similar often implement none of the published patterns at all. Popular frameworks like to incorporate famous pattern names as a means of self promotion.